# Zpool Import, one or more devices is currently unavailable

Tags: zfs, proxmox, openmediavault

I know this is a pretty common question, but I haven't found a situation quite like mine.
To cut it short, I had a ZFS pool on my home server on bare metal of proxmox, wanted to move it to an open media vault installation. It went fine, but then i removed the zfs storage from proxmox, not realizing i put the stupid OS drive of the OMV installation on that zfs pool... So then I attempt to export the pool, and create a whole new OMV installation, and am now unable to reimport it.
All of the pool seems fine and healthy, all disks are showing online, it is just refusing to import. And since its my home setup and I haven't got the money for a secondary proper backup, this was all I had of my Plex collection.. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.[commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krnjG.png)

My current thought process is to turn it into a read-only pool (if that works) and then copy that to an external drive I have and recreate the pool. Would prefer if I didn't have to do that, but I understand I screwed myself as is.
I attempted to import as read-only and this is what came up now.
[Second round of commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zceSE.png)
Well here is something new atleast..? [zpool import -T 1642334 -o readonly=on -d /dev/disk/by-id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RpXN.png)

### zdb -eul -p /dev/disk/by-id/ bulk_storage

### LABEL 0

```
version: 5000
name: 'bulk_storage'
state: 0
txg: 1642334
pool_guid: 14313209163207667065
errata: 0
hostid: 124007166
hostname: 'openmediavault'
top_guid: 2798799799687839903
guid: 14439541404213189640
vdev_children: 1
vdev_tree:
    type: 'raidz'
    id: 0
    guid: 2798799799687839903
    nparity: 1
    metaslab_array: 256
    metaslab_shift: 34
    ashift: 12
    asize: 12002315993088
    is_log: 0
    create_txg: 4
    children[0]:
        type: 'disk'
        id: 0
        guid: 5289805472172966462
        path: '/dev/sdb1'
        devid: 'ata-ST4000DM004-2CV104_ZTT4K3XC-part1'
        phys_path: 'pci-0000:03:00.1-ata-3.0'
        whole_disk: 1
        DTL: 5689
        create_txg: 4
    children[1]:
        type: 'disk'
        id: 1
        guid: 12592786367764665655
        path: '/dev/sdc1'
        devid: 'ata-ST4000DM004-2CV104_ZTT4KKYP-part1'
        phys_path: 'pci-0000:03:00.1-ata-8.0'
        whole_disk: 1
        DTL: 5688
        create_txg: 4
    children[2]:
        type: 'disk'
        id: 2
        guid: 14439541404213189640
        path: '/dev/sdd1'
        devid: 'ata-ST4000DM004-2CV104_ZTT4KW0Q-part1'
        phys_path: 'pci-0000:03:00.1-ata-1.0'
        whole_disk: 1
        DTL: 5687
        create_txg: 4
features_for_read:
    com.delphix:hole_birth
    com.delphix:embedded_data
labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[0]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642752
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932381 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:01 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[1]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642753
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932386 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:06 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[2]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642754
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932391 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:11 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[3]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642755
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932397 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:17 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[4]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642756
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932402 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:22 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[5]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642757
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932407 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:27 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[6]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642758
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932412 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:32 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[7]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642759
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932417 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:37 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[8]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642760
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932422 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:42 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[9]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642761
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932427 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:47 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[10]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642762
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932432 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:52 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[11]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642763
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932438 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:53:58 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[12]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642764
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932443 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:54:03 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[13]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642765
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932448 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:54:08 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[14]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642766
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932453 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:54:13 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[15]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642767
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932458 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:54:18 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[16]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642768
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932463 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:54:23 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[17]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642769
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932468 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:54:28 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[18]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642770
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932473 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:54:33 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[19]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642771
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932475 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:54:35 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[20]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642740
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932319 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:51:59 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[21]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642741
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932324 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:04 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[22]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642742
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932330 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:10 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[23]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642743
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932335 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:15 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[24]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642744
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932340 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:20 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[25]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642745
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932346 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:26 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[26]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642746
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932351 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:31 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[27]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642747
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932356 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:36 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[28]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642748
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932361 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:41 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[29]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642749
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932366 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:46 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[30]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642750
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932371 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:51 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
Uberblock[31]
    magic = 0000000000bab10c
    version = 5000
    txg = 1642751
    guid_sum = 12540654059627225493
    timestamp = 1706932376 UTC = Fri Feb  2 21:52:56 2024
    mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
    mmp_delay = 0
    mmp_valid = 0
    checkpoint_txg = 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: If you check the commands you will see recommendation to use `-f`. Did you use it?

Comment: In the screenshot I provided it shows that I did. I attempted to import as read-only, then it gives me an insufficient replicas error... not looking good.

Comment: The right order of options is `-f -p option......`

Comment: For what command, import? Thats not a valid option it says